# No values in the variables when querying a sesame repository?

Tags: java, sesame

I want to use a .nt file as a SESAME repository and query it (also called local federation mode). The program written is as follows.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import org.openrdf.OpenRDFException;
import org.openrdf.repository.RepositoryConnection;
import org.openrdf.model.Value;
import org.openrdf.query.TupleQuery;
import org.openrdf.query.TupleQueryResult;
import org.openrdf.query.BindingSet;
import org.openrdf.query.QueryLanguage;
import org.openrdf.repository.Repository;
import org.openrdf.repository.sail.SailRepository;
import org.openrdf.sail.nativerdf.NativeStore;

public class QuerySesameLocal {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try
    {

        File dataDir = new File("/home/aidb/out0.nt");
        Repository repo = new SailRepository(new NativeStore(dataDir));
        repo.initialize();

               RepositoryConnection con = repo.getConnection();
               try {
                  String queryString = "SELECT ?x ?y WHERE { ?x ?p ?y } ";
                  TupleQuery tupleQuery = con.prepareTupleQuery(QueryLanguage.SPARQL, queryString);

                  TupleQueryResult result = tupleQuery.evaluate();
                  try {

                      if(result.hasNext())
                      {
                          System.out.println("result present");
                      }

                      System.out.println("checkpoint 1");
                        BindingSet bindingSet = result.next();
                        Value valueOfX = bindingSet.getValue("x");
                        Value valueOfY = bindingSet.getValue("y");

                        System.out.println(valueOfX.toString());
                          System.out.println("checkpoint 2");

                        // do something interesting with the values here...
                  }
                  finally {
                      result.close();
                  }
               }
               finally {
                  con.close();
               }
            }
            catch (OpenRDFException e) {
               // handle exception
            }


}
```

}

This program does not return any results at all. I tried figuring the bug but could not figure out. Can anyone kindly tell what is wrong with the program ?

Comment: Replace `// handle exception` by `throw new RuntimeException(e);`, then execute the program again, and read/paste the full stack trace of the exception, if any. Ignoring exceptions is the best way to not know what happens. Also, learn to use your debugger. It isn't that hard.

Comment: @harry potter as an aside, I noticed that you have asked a number of questions on SO and have received several answers, but have yet to vote on/accept any of them. I'd encourage you to do so (not just on this question here but on any of your older ones as well). Have a look at this: [what should I do when someone answers?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

You can't just initialize a Sesame Native Store with an .nt file (or any other rdf file) like this.

The `dataDir` argument of the `NativeStore` constructor is a directory where the native store will create its indexes and store added data - it stores this data in its own internal format by the way, not as .nt files. So you should pass it a directory, not a file (in fact I am a bit surprised that you don't get an error when executing this code).

Once the repository is created and initialized, you have to add the file to it. You do this by opening a `RepositoryConnection` and using one of its `add` methods to pass the file to it. See the [Sesame user documentation](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/docs/users.docbook?view), specifically the section on [how to add data to a repository](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/docs/users.docbook?view#section-repository-api2).

Comment: As mentioned I initialized a repository, got a connection and then gave it the .nt file. It worked fine. Thanks a lot!